# список нужно принимать в аргументах, а не определять в функции

Tags: python

выдаёт верный ответ, но в автотесте выдаёт ошибку[image: скрин автотеста]

Задача:

> Для соревнований по волейболу необходимо сформировать турнирнирную сетку из восьми человек на два дня. На первый день из списка участников решили выбрать каждого второго. Дан список из восьми имён: Артемий, Борис, Влад, Гоша, Дима, Евгений, Женя, Захар. Напишите программу, которая выводит элементы списка только с чётными индексами. Пример: Первый день: ['Артемий', 'Влад', 'Дима', 'Женя']

```
def display_result(participants_names):

    print('Первый день:', participants_names)

def get_participants_names(names):

    names_list = ['Артемий', 'Борис', 'Влад', 'Гоша', 'Дима', 'Евгений', 'Женя', 'Захар']
    names = []
    for i in range(0, len(names_list) - 1, 2):
        names.append(names_list[i])

    return names

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Это условие необходимо, чтобы в рамках автотестов не произошёл
    # вызов функций get_participants_names и display_result
    participants_names = get_participants_names(
        ["Артемий", "Борис", "Влад", "Гоша", "Дима", "Евгений", "Женя", "Захар"]
    )  # получаем список имён с чётными индексами
    display_result(participants_names)  # выводим результат
```

Comment: Уберите из функции строку `names_list = ['Артемий', 'Борис', 'Влад', 'Гоша', 'Дима', 'Евгений', 'Женя', 'Захар']`, переименуйте параметр names в names_list.

Comment: спасибо, помогло